# How to add an anchor point on the exact 0.618 point of a line in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to add an anchor point on a line to divide it into 0.618 of its length and 0.382 of its length. How can this be done? If I need to do this quickly every time, is there a good method?

Comment: You can draw it as two lines, you can script the split

Answer (score 1):

With snapping on, draw a horizontal line touching the left edge of the page. Holding down Shift as you click and drag with the Line tool will constrain it horizontally, and then make sure it is 100mm wide by inputting the value numerically

[image]

With the Add Anchor point tool, add an anchor point somewhere on the line, select the anchor, and input the X value as 68.1mm

[image]

If you want more lines or lines of different size, just copy and paste this, and rescale them, rotate them, etc. The ratio of the two segments will be preserved.

If you want to apply it to a curved line (or a straight line) you have already drawn, break the original path at its anchor using the Cut Path at Selected Anchor Point button in the bar along the top. Select the two pieces and click and drag into the brushes dialog, and make an Art Brush.

To use this, draw a curved/straight line, then apply the brush you made, and do *Object > Expand Appearance*, and then do *Object > Ungroup*.  You will will now have two separate segments at the correct length ratio.

[image]